# Error when using Spate Media Library: "BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User::addMediaFromRequest()"

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

This is my User Model

```
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia;
    use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait;
    use Spatie\MediaLibrary\File;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable  implements HasMedia

    {

        use HasMediaTrait;
        use Notifiable;

        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password',
        ];

        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];

        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];

        public function role(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App/Role');
        }


    }
```

This is my UserController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user=new User;
        $user->name=($request['name']);
        $user->email=($request['email']);
        $password=bcrypt($request['password']);
        $user->password=$password;

        $user_photo=$request['photo'];

        $user->addMediaFromRequest('photo')->toMediaCollection('images');


        $user->save();
        return redirect('/admin');

    }
}
```

I want to use *Spatie* Media Library and upload a photo for each user but I get this error related to *Spatie* Library:

> "Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User::addMediaFromRequest()".

I have read some related posts but I don't understand how to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: What version of the library are you using?

Comment: Version 7 because i have Laravel 5.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 8 of the library has this documentation. Are you using the correct trait?

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class YourModel extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;
}
```

**Edited:**

On another note, using `HasMediaTrait` is for version 7 so I assume you're using version 7. I think it's because you're importing the wrong `User` class. The `User` class used to implement `HasMedia` lies in the `App\User` namespace. But you're importing the `User` class from the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` namespace. So change it to `use App\User;` and you should be fine.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user=new User;
        $user->name=($request['name']);
        $user->email=($request['email']);
        $password=bcrypt($request['password']);
        $user->password=$password;

        $user_photo=$request['photo'];

        $user->addMediaFromRequest('photo')->toMediaCollection('images');


        $user->save();
        return redirect('/admin');

    }
}
```

https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/basic-usage/preparing-your-model/

Comment: I've changed "App/User" instead of "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User" inside my UserController and it works.